Miniconda Env same path but no name
I'm running conda info --envs in VSCode's terminal, and I can see two environments.
PS C:\Users\Abbou\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding\AI-Customer-Support-> conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\Users\Abbou\miniconda3
                         c:\Users\Abbou\miniconda3

Can someone explain to me what the unnamed second environment is, and how I can delete it?
I'm new to Miniconda, so it may be something I did incorrectly, or just something normal that I do not understand.
